# Confusion with C syntax (relating to pointer and ampersand)

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, ampersand

Through this website, http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html, I am now learning C programming and now I am trying to understand the codes written there. So, I know about the basic pointer, and all of the stuffs that associated to it, at least I think so.

I came up with this code from above's URL (below's code is simplified):

```
void Database_get(struct Connection *conn, int id)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
}
```

Does the Right Hand Side of the above's code means `&(conn->db->rows[id])` or `(&conn)->db->rows[id]`? From the way I look at it, it means `&(conn->db->rows[id])`. Sorry if this is a basic stuff. Still in the midst of learning. Already tried to Google this stuff, can't seems to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept you’re looking for is [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). In C and C++, `->` and `[]` have higher precedence than `&`. Moreover, `->` and `[]` have left-to-right associativity, so they are resolved in this order:

```
&(((conn->db)->rows)[id])
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.